# 32 bit and its relation with Ram?

Tags: operating-system, cpu

1. Does 32 bit mean ram size should be 4GB ? or can a computer with say 32GB ram also have 32 bit provided adress space does not exceed 32 bit ?
2. When we say 32-bit windows or 64-bit OS, which part of OS exactly differs between the two ? I mean does some part of kernel differ ? if yes then which part ?

NOTE: this question is not a duplicate. please dont vote to close

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the relation between 32/64-bit application, OS and processor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808014/whats-the-relation-between-32-64-bit-application-os-and-processor)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This question is not a duplicate, please dont vote to close

Comment: Which posts of your question are not answered by that previous question and its answers?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Does 32 bit mean ram size should be 4GB ?

Comment: I think the answer in the duplicate question explains very well the memory restrictions of 32-bit applications.  It explains both virtual and physical limits.

Answer (score 4):

No 32-bit does not necessarily refer to the size of the address bus. If the address bus is 32-bit then certainly the maximum RAM in the system is 4 gb, or 2^32. There have been several examples of 32-bit machines that could exceed 4gb of RAM, however, by using a concept of Page-Extended Addressing (PAE) That was introduces in the mid 1990s.

Another examples where this comes into play is the first IBM PC. It used a 16-bit microprocessor known as the 8088. The 8088 had a 20-bit address line and as such had the capacity of 2^20 (1MB) of RAM.

When we speak of a microprocessor having a certain number of 'bits', such as a 16-bit microprocessor or a 32-bit microprocessor, we are primarily referring to the basic data unit that the processor can handle at a time. This is determined by the size of the processor registers, which are the areas of the processor used for holding data for calculations and decisions.

Because there is a fundamental difference in how machine code is used to grab and process data in a 32-bit vs a 64-bit system, All code must be compiled specifically for the machine you want it to run on. This is why there are two version of many x86 operating systems. There is often one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit x86. x86 microprocessors have a legacy of backwards compatibility and are therefore able to run in 16, 32, or 64-bit modes. This means that you can run 32-bit windows on a 64-bit processor. If this backwards compatibility wasn't build in, however, this would not be possible.

So, as far as which part of the kernel differs, the answer is all of it. The same is true for desktop applications that are coded for 64-bit machines. If they have two versions, the entire code is different as the compiler optimizes for one or the other.